# Question about Moments and Extending Inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Here is the problem: You have random variables $x,y$. Each has finite moments.  We have $$\mathbb{E}|x|^k\leq \mathbb{E}|y|^k$$ for all integers $k\geq 1$. Must it be true that $$\mathbb{E}|x|^p\leq \mathbb{E}|y|^p$$ for all real $p\geq 1$?

Original: Suppose you have a probability space $\Omega$ with the following property: There exists a random variable $Y$ such that $\mathbb{E}|x|^k\leq \mathbb{E}|Y|^k$ for all integers $k\geq 1$ and all random variables $x$. Is it necessarily true that $\mathbb{E}|x|^p\leq \mathbb{E}|Y|^p$ for real $p\geq 1$ and all random variables $x$? I just thought of this randomly and cannot convince myself one way or the other.

Comment: Can you think of a probability space where $Y$ is not constant (I tried to cook up one, but I was not able to to, but I am also not a probabilist)?

Comment: You also want to fix the target. If the target is $\mathbb{R}^n$, then such a $Y$ cannot exist (consider $2Y$ which will have larger expectation than $Y$).

Comment: There must be a normalization. For example $${E|X|^p\over (E|X|)^p}\le {E|Y|^p\over (E|Y|)^p}$$

Comment: Perhaps you want to assume this for a specific $x$ rather than all $x$?

Comment: Thanks. I did end up changing the question.